# EF6 Caching Local Data on Crash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to figure out what exactly is causing this error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Draft_dbo.GameEvent_GameEventId". The conflict occurred in database "Azularis", table "dbo.GameEvent", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Now the thing is, in my database when I run the select statement, the table GameEvent is empty.  Here is the code that causes the error

```
for (var i = 0; i < totalTeams / 2; i++)
{
    var game = new GameEvent
    {
        GameOrderNo = i + 1,
        EventId = eventId,
        RoundNo = 1
    };
    Db.GameEvents.Add(game);
}
if (await Db.SaveChangesAsync() > 0) //It crashes here
{
    Db.Drafts.Add(CreateDraft(teamIds.First(), game.Id, -1, 1));
    await Db.SaveChangesAsync() > 0
}
```

The logic above is incomplete as I am still developing this, however the crash happens on `if (await Db.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)`

Now if I delete the database and I run this, it works with no problems, records get saved and no error.  If for whatever the reason code crashes and I go and delete the records and run this again I get the above error.

What I have noticed is that if I hover over Db.Draft, and I look at Local property, it has records still there, it did not dump them from the cache and I am assuming it is trying to write same PK twice so it crashes.

That is my theory and I do not understand it, any help is most appreciated.

EDIT:
My other theory (Which I think is more likely than the first) is that Draft was cached and it is trying to write those records, and as GameEvent is empty, it cannot insert as there are no primary keys to reference.

As such, how do I force it to dump this cache when the code crashes?  In production environment if for whatever the reason this were to happen, nobody is going to be able to insert more data.

The only way for me to get past this error above is to delete and recreate the database at the moment.

EDIT 2:

Here is how I replicate:
I Start with fresh database and I run it once.  The code will draft on `Db.Drafts.Add` because teamId will be null.  Then I go back to database and I truncate draft table, and then I delete all records from GameEvent table.

I run the code again and this time it fails on this simple test scenario:

```
var test = new GameEvent
{
   GameOrderNo = 1,
   EventId = new Guid("1e48bd5b-58ab-e511-a551-e03f497d18e0"),
   RoundNo = 1
};

Db.GameEvents.Add(test);
await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

EDIT 3:

Schema is generated from the following code:

```
public class GameEvent
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public int GameOrderNo { get; set; }
    public int RoundNo { get; set; }
}

public class Draft
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }
    public Guid GameEventId { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
    public int Placement { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    public virtual GameEvent GameEvent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: have you looked in the database..? do you know what a foreign key constraint is.. perhaps you already have that id in the table you are trying to insert delete the data from the database for that record and try again and if it works then sounds like you have an issue with generating the correct Id key field is my best guess

Comment: @MethodMan table is completely empty

Comment: have you refreshed your edmx file why don't you try doing this without using EF to see if it works as a test ..

Comment: @MethodMan I am using SQL Server database, and I'm not sure what edmx file is.

Comment: and yes If I go to SQL Server Studio I can insert a record without problems as long as I put in the correct EventId which is also a FK

Comment: can you show the actual Insert statement how are you using EF and not know what the file types are anyway.. why don't you just create a test function that inserts the data into the database.. can you show the database schema.. so that we can see the foreign key relationship

Comment: I updated my question.  If you are downvoting at least explain why, how else will I know what is wrong with my question.

Comment: I am curious why you are hard coding a GUID when you should use something like this to generate a new GUID
`var newGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` also still would like to see the Database Schema for the tables that you are using

Comment: that hard coded guid is a foreign key and i just threw it there for the example.  As for the schema I'll update my question

Comment: did you do codefirst or was the database already generated first.. in regards to using this attribute `[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` you need to remove the  public Guid EventId { get; set; } or the foreignkey value.. run update database.. then re-add it and run update database again

Comment: can the tables be recreated if you drop them using the code first approach..? I am not all that familiar with code first.. we always create / generate our tables first when using EF in our environment

Comment: Curious - what happens if you comment out the Db.Drafts.Add line? I'm guessing it fails on the second insert every time, regardless of any drafts being added.

Comment: Also, is this the ONLY database code that executes as part of your test case? EF caches in-memory and tracks changes entirely in-memory with no external cache. If you believe Drafts are being re-inserted, it's probably caused by some code that is not shown.

Comment: the only hits to the database are in the code that I have shown, above, the only other thing is I am calling `await Db.SaveChangesAsync() after the last line of code shown, I'll update the question.

Comment: Where do you initiate `Db` and how long does it live?

Comment: I have a BaseController that is extended by every controller which has a class variable such as `protected static ApplicationDbContext Db = new ApplicationDbContext();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Db`'s lifespan is too long. **You should *never* use static contexts**.

When you create the `Draft` and `GameEvent`s for the first time, EF first has the new objects in cache as `Added` and after saving them, they are `Unchanged`.

Now you delete everything from the database and do the same thing again. You create new entities that will be marked as `Added` but that have associations to entities that are still in cache as `Unchanged`. Now EF will only emit `INSERT` statements for the `Added` entities, and not for the `Unchanged` ones. But the inserted records do have FK's pointing to records that you just deleted manually.

From your description it's hard to follow what *exactly* happens, but I'm sure you will be out of trouble if you use a new context for each database interaction.

Comment: so you suggesting that I change `protected static ApplicationDbContext Db = new ApplicationDbContext();` to `protected ApplicationDbContext Db = new ApplicationDbContext();` in my BaseController?

Comment: If this is an MVC controller (as the tags indicate), yes, because a new controller is created for each request. You may have to fetch existing entities from the database first though.

Comment: Ok, could you give me an example of how I would do that?  The whole reason for me doing a static was to avoid creating too many, if one exists it should be reused.

Comment: You better ask a new question for that, because this question has become hard to follow ( for instance, I don't understand the role of `EventId`). Show one clear sample case of what you do now and try to get it working with a transient context. But generally I think you should try to fetch an existing entity from the database and create a new one only if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, I will do that, but can you answer me one more thing so I can ask that question with more understanding.  When you say fetch existing entities, are you refering to a database connection, tables?  This part confuses me and that is why I was asking for the example.

Comment: Yes, just a query like `context.GameEvents.Find(someIdValue)`.